# UTC entry in Gnome Clock

Tags: gnome, clock, gnome-clocks

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and found that the UTC entry of the World Clock is no longer there. Searching for UTC, GMT or similar keywords does not help:

[image: screenshot of search box]

I searched the Internet, and found very old bug reports ([here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692243) and [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/issues/61)) that seem to indicate that the feature was requested by other users in the past, and so it is unlikely that it was intentionally removed.

Is there any way to restore this functionality without installing a plugin?

Comment: I have `gnome-clocks` v. 41.0, installed through `apt`, and it certainly has an UTC entry ("Coordinated Universal Time"). Did you install it through `snap` maybe?

Comment: I upgraded from 18.04 to 22.04 via `apt dist-upgrade`: my version of `gnome-clocks` (read through the UI) is also 41.0, `dpkg -s "gnome-clocks"` reports "installed", while `snap list` does not have an entry for `gnome-clocks`. It does have two entries for gnome, though... not sure what is going on.

Comment: What is the version of `tzdata` on your system? Do `apt policy tzdata`.

Comment: That gives `2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0` for both "Installed" and "Candidate". Trying `apt-get install tzdata` also confirms that it is the latest version.

Comment: I cloned the `gnome-clocks` repository and took a look around. It seems that the location database is taken from `GWeather`.  I think the locations are taken from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgweather/Locations.bin`.  Do you have such a file, and does `grep` reveal that the word UTC is in there?

Comment: Related question: is `gir1.2-gweather-3.0` installed on your system? Perhaps even `gir1.2-gweather-4.0`?

Comment: `gir1.2-gweather-3.0` is installed, `gir1.2-gweather-4.0` was not; I then installed the latter, but it seems to make no difference. `grep UTC /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgweather/Locations.bin` says `binary file matches` .

Comment: Found [something](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libgweather/-/issues/18) that might be a lead to the source of the problem: `python3 -c "from gi.repository import GWeather; print(GWeather.Location.get_world().get_timezones()[0].get_identifier())"` prints "UTC", so the timezone is defintely there. However, it has no code, so it cannot be serialized. And in fact, adding it "manually" via gsetting does not work. @Jos would you share the result of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell.world-clocks locations` while UTC is enabled?

Comment: The output is `[<(uint32 2, <('Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)', '@UTC', false, @a(dd) [], @a(dd) [])>)>]`.

Comment: Hey, what do you know! That (sorta) worked: I can see an entry in the dropdown (which pops open when clicking on the clock bar), although it is not there when I open the application itself. The only problem is, it says "GMT"... [close enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48960297), I guess! Thanks, @Jos!